# Dropdown value disappears when I move to next dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am trying to scrape some data using the following code. When I run the code line by line, it works fine. However, when I want to run all code at one go, the dropdown options go blank and as a result, the last line returns error. Your help would be much appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import os

path = os.path.join(r"D:\ScrapedData\TN\SocialAudit")
path_to_chromedriver = 'D:\ScrapedData/chromedriver'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : path}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options ,executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)    

url = "http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/SocialAudit/StateList.aspx"
browser.get(url)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(45)
browser.maximize_window()

browser.find_element_by_link_text("BIHAR").click()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

year=['2016-2017', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2019-2020']
elem2 = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlFin")
elem2.send_keys(year[0])
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

select_dist = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddldist")
options = [x for x in select_dist.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
dist=[]
for e in range(len(options)):
    select_dist = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddldist"))
    select_dist.select_by_index(e)

    select_block = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlblock"))
    options1 = select_block.options
    for f in range(len(options1)):
        select_block = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlblock"))
        select_block.select_by_index(f)

        select_gp = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlpanchayat"))
        options2 = select_gp.options
        for g in range(len(options2)):
           select_gp = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlpanchayat"))
           select_gp.select_by_index(g)

           browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbLoginLevel_1").click()
           browser.implicitly_wait(10)

           elem6 = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtperiodFrom")
           elem6.send_keys('01/04/2016')
           browser.implicitly_wait(10)

           elem7 = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtperiodTo")
           elem7.send_keys('31/03/2017')
           browser.implicitly_wait(10)

           browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_login").click()
           browser.implicitly_wait(10)

           browser.find_element_by_link_text("Download All Reports").click()
```

Comment: can you put a executable code , it doesn't have  browser or options defined. Just add the entire code that could be executed so that we can debug it

Comment: Hi, I have edited the above codes to include the whole module

Comment: why are you iterating over options ? its throwing erro option doesn't have property length

Comment: These are conditional dropdowns. I am iterating so that I don't need to select the district, block and Panchayat name everytime I complete downloading the file. When I run these codes line by line, it works very much fine, but in a lop environment it does not work

Comment: in your code options is chrome.options , why u want to iterate over it .

Comment: Hey @PDHide, I noticed the error now. I rectified it; however, it still does not work

Comment: I don't know how it worked for you select by index , will select 0th element which is select-district . Even if u run line by line it shouldn't work . Could you check the code really works when u run line by line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

import time
import os

path = os.path.join(r"D:\ScrapedData\TN\SocialAudit")
path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\Users\prave\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : path}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options ,executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)    

url = "http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/SocialAudit/StateList.aspx"
browser.get(url)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(45)
browser.maximize_window()

browser.find_element_by_link_text("BIHAR").click()


year=['2016-2017', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2019-2020']
elem2 = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlFin")
elem2.send_keys(year[0])
time.sleep(4)

select_dist = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddldist")
options = [x for x in select_dist.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
len(options)
dist=[]
for e in range(1,len(options)):
    select_dist = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddldist"))
    select_dist.select_by_index(e)
    time.sleep(4)
    select_block = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlblock"))
    a =select_dist
    options1 = select_block.options
    for f in range(1,len(options1)):
        select_block = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlblock"))
        select_block.select_by_index(f)
        time.sleep(4)
        select_gp = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlpanchayat"))
        options2 = select_gp.options
        for g in range(1,len(options2)):
           select_gp = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlpanchayat"))
           select_gp.select_by_index(g)

           time.sleep(4)

           browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbLoginLevel_1").click()
           time.sleep(4)

           elem6 = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtperiodFrom")
           elem6.send_keys('01/04/2016')
           time.sleep(4)

           elem7 = browser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtperiodTo")
           elem7.send_keys('31/03/2017')
           time.sleep(4)

           browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_login").click()
           time.sleep(4)

           browser.find_element_by_link_text("Download All Reports").click()
```

**Explanation:**

1. Your range was starting from '0' and the 0th element was "select_something". So changed it to range(1,len(a)) , so range starts from 1.
2. Don't use implicit wait, it will make the entire code slow, use time.sleep() or explicit wait instead. Here we used time.sleep() (  Recommended is an explicit wait )

**Note:**

I am not sure how your code worked for you when executed line by line, it should fail due to an alert saying "Select all drop-down" before proceeding.

Comment: Wonderful. It's working fine. Thank you so much. So, the key was using time.sleep.

Comment: @Bidhu no the issue was that you used range starting from 0

Comment: Okay.  A follow-up question: when I run the "download all reports", it opens a new tab. As a result, the code interrupts. I am wondering if there is a way to prevent changing the focus of tab to the one with dropdowns

Comment: read about switching tab in selenium

Comment: Yes, I am already into that.